# If a planet has no atmosphere would bodies on it rot?

Tags: atmosphere

Not sure if this is the right place, but I'm working on some sci-fi.

If bodies were left on a planet without an atmosphere (not in a spacesuit or anything), would the body rot? I can't find any answers with a quick google, so I thought I would ask here!

Thanks for any information!

Comment: What's the temperature range on your airless planet? Or to ask the same question a different way, what kind of star does it orbit, and how far is it from said star. This makes a huge difference to what happens to the body.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on where they are left, especially the temperature. Bodies would not rot in the traditional sense  but might be subject to chemical decomposition. If they were in a very cold environment they would freeze and might remain that way indefinitely. In warmer conditions the body would quickly dry out. If they were somewhere very hot then the bodies would dry out and mummify.

If subjected to temperature cycling the decomposition could be fairly quick due to freeze thaw action disrupting the dried body. Leading to crumpling of the freeze dried flesh. bones might remain for a long time before disintegrating.

Comment: I think "dry out" will be the main thing.  In a vacuum, water boils,.  All the water will leave the body, quickly.  Even if it is cold enough to freeze the ice will sublimate away.

Comment: True unless the temperature is very low in which case the ice might remain - as in the case of the Moon's polar ice and similar